# Shared preference and SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to confirm my understanding about sharedPreference and SQLite. Please help me.

shared preference

1. store private primitive data in key-value pair.
2. Useful for store small amount of data
3. Data stored in xml file, and without encryption. Thus it is not secure.
4. Able to access by other apps. Not secure.

SQLite

1. Does not require any server, it store locally in the mobile device.
2. Useful for store small or large amount of data.
3. Data stored is encrypted. Thus more secure.
4. Not accessible outside the app. Thus more secure.

Please correct me if anything wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I would disagree that sqlite data is secure because it is encrypted, it is secure because data belongs to the app. Other apps need permission to use your app or its data. You can grant permission via pending intent or same vendor credentials(package name,certificate...) More or less you are correct

Comment: Others app need permission to use another app data which is stored in SQLite.   What bout shared preference?  Do sharedPreference need permission ?

Comment: Caution: If you create a shared preferences file with MODE_WORLD_READABLE or MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, then any other apps that know the file identifier can access your data.
here is the link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference so @Kai you can share shared preferences if you want to according to the documentation. You have a good understanding already these are just some fine points. I hope I don't confuse you.

Comment: @Kai preferences are  generally used for settings like default username, color theme etc. SQLite is user data. Preferences use key value pair so any preference needs a unique key

Answer (score 2):

SP-1. is Correct. So is SQLite-1. However SQLite cannot directly store Boolean, the minimum is 1 byte which can be used as a Boolean. SQLite can store byte arrays as BLOBs other than that the type of data that can be stored is very much the same.

SP-2. Is basically correct and so is SQLite-2. However, you could argue that you could usefully save large amounts of data in shared preferences. When it boils down to it they are both files.

3/4. The data is stored with the same protection (using the default for SQLite) which is private to the App. However, there is an option to encrypt the database. Access by other App's has to be given. Obviously rooted devices are an exception.

In short they are quite similar except when it comes to the data being structured when SQLite leaps ahead of shared preferences in manageability capabilities.

Comment: OK thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are somewhere correct, so I want to add some more points.

**Shared Preference:**

1. Shared preference is also secure. If you set shared preference as a `private_mode`.
2. `Storing` the data in `cache memory`..
3. Shared preferences can only store key-value pairings whilst an SQLite database is much more flexible.

**SQLite**

1. SQlite provides database at mobile/device just like another RDBMS. If you uninstall the application. The database will also get deleted.
2. We can't see our database directly, for this you need some applications (needs ROOT permissions).

For more information you can [visit here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).

Comment: Shared preference data is stored in cache memory , in xml format? So if i clear cache, all data will gone?

Answer (score 0):

That’s not true because we can’t tell the deference between Shared Preference and SQLite. 
Shared preferences is something like windows registry and we use share preferences when we want to store some small configuration data and it’s safe and has many ways to close access from other applications.

But SQLite is a database and the main data that you are working with , should be there and it’s safe and has good speed and saving and retrieving data is very fast and easily.

Good Luck

Comment: How do u say that SQLite has good speed in saving and retrieve data?